# How Should I assign the next approver in the Approval process as the Owner of the Record in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

There are at least 2 approvers to approve a record sequentially. I want the owner to be assigned as the 1st Approver when the record is submitted for approval, then to the 2nd approver when the record is approved by the 1st approver, and so on.

The code for the first approver to be assigned is as follows -

```
           if(reg.OwnerId != reg.Approver_1__c)
             reg.OwnerId = reg.Approver_1__c;
```

How do I set the owner as the next approver in the approval process?

Comment: Please consider rewording this for clarity. Particularly your title. You are mixing upper case and lower case haphazardly.  Additionally what you are asking for is vague. From what you wrote you are saying the person who currently owns the item should be assigned as the 1st approver when submitted, and then the owner should again become the 2nd approver... I think what you mean is that you want the first approver to be the owner, and then the second approver the owner.. that is the current person who needs to take action is the owner.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of Approvers, with the ids of the people you want to be the approvers, something like this:

```
List<Id> approvers = new List<Id>();
approvers.add(Owner.Id);
approvers.add(Whoever_is_next_ID);
```

then set that list as the next approvers of your approval process

```
List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest> requests = new 
List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest>();

        for (Id approverId : approvers) {
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();

            req.setComments('Approving _____...');
            req.setObjectId(yourObject to approve ID);
            req.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{approverId});

            requests.add(req);
        }
```

Hope this is useful

Comment: But my issue is that I want to mark the approver as the owner of that record. I already have the Approvers on the record detail. The next approvere should be the owner of the record. I tried to do this on the Object Trigger. Its sort of works. But the Owner is not updated as soon as the record is approved. It is updated only when the record is updates (because of before update trigger)

Comment: is it possible to add a field change action to the record, in the after approved actions,, would that count as an update to the record?...

Comment: So I created a custom field called 'Last Approved Date' and added it to field change in the approval Actions. The, I used that field to trigger the owner update. I used <ProcessInstance> to get actorId and assign it as Owner. I used this query - 
List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> PworkItem = 
[Select ProcessInstance.Status, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId, ActorId From ProcessInstanceWorkitem where ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending' and ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId in: List];

But this is assigning it to the previous approver and not to the next approver.

Comment: I understand that that the the field update and the trigger is occurring in the same operation, so it is getting the old value.